# Mercurial API: reading config over https

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-api

In the Mercurial API, is there any way to read the configuration values associated with a repository that you're accessing over HTTPS? The repository's `ui` object doesn't seem to hold them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "no". There is no way to read the config values from a repo over HTTP using the Mercurial API.  These values are never transmitted over the network.  A more detailed explanation follows.

---

The `ui.ui()` class provides access to system, user and local repository config values.

```
>>> from mercurial import hg, ui
>>> u = ui.ui()
>>> u.configlist('ui', 'username')
['Your', 'Name', '<your@email.com>']
```

The constructor for a repository object requires a `ui` object and a `path` to be provided.

The values from `ui` are copied into the repo object.

If `path` is a local repository, then the config settings for that repository may be accessed via `repo.ui`.  However if `path` is a URL, the API does not query the remote server for config settings.  In that case, `repo.ui` only includes the system and user settings.

```
>>> repo = hg.repository(ui.ui(), '.')
>>> repo.ui.configlist('paths', 'default')
['https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg']

... start an hg serve session at http://localhost:8000 ...

>>> repo = hg.repository(ui.ui(), 'http://localhost:8000')
>>> repo.ui.configlist('paths', 'default')
[]
```